# Why Activity Indicator not Showing?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

This is my `XAML` code am trying to put an `ActivityIndicator` on top of other Views , but it's not showing at all why ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" BackgroundImage="background_nonedit.png" Title="Citizen Reporter" x:Class="BBSTV.CitizenReporter">
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="10" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}">
                <Grid x:Name="SegmentGrid" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
                <Image x:Name="citizenImage" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="220" />
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="8" x:Name="attachment_label" />
                <Entry Placeholder="News Title" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" />
                <Entry Placeholder="News Details" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="90" />
                <Button Text="CHOOSE PHOTO" Margin="8" Clicked="onChoosePhoto" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="TAKE  PHOTO" Margin="8" Clicked="onTakePhoto" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="CHOOSE VIDEO" Margin="8" Clicked="onChooseVideo" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="TAKE VIDEO" Margin="8" Clicked="onTakeVideo" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="UPLOAD REPORT" Margin="9" Clicked="UploadFile_Clicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#F399FC  " />
            </StackLayout>

            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity_i_citizenReport" Color="Black" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relative layout will place your controls in-relation to it's siblings, so it'll likely render the stack layout over the top of your indicator, or just below it and out of sight. This is documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/).

I would simply put it on the outside of your scrollview, as the scroll view has a variable content size so it can sometimes be a bit difficult to calculate a dead centre, whereas if you assign the activity control to the content page directly it'll always be in the centre. You might have to have a play around with the Z-Index if the below doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" BackgroundImage="background_nonedit.png" Title="Citizen Reporter" x:Class="BBSTV.CitizenReporter">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity_i_citizenReport" Color="Black" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="10" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}">
                <Grid x:Name="SegmentGrid" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
                <Image x:Name="citizenImage" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="220" />
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="8" x:Name="attachment_label" />
                <Entry Placeholder="News Title" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" />
                <Entry Placeholder="News Details" Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="90" />
                <Button Text="CHOOSE PHOTO" Margin="8" Clicked="onChoosePhoto" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="TAKE  PHOTO" Margin="8" Clicked="onTakePhoto" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="CHOOSE VIDEO" Margin="8" Clicked="onChooseVideo" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="TAKE VIDEO" Margin="8" Clicked="onTakeVideo" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4D7EE1" />
                <Button Text="UPLOAD REPORT" Margin="9" Clicked="UploadFile_Clicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#F399FC  " />
            </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
      </ScrollView>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: In which case, I'd have a look at the other answer, as a default the activity indicator is not set as 'running' so it might be worth setting these methods and trying again.

Comment: I don't think this code will work as published. Content can have only one child and in the code I see 2 - Indicator ans ScrollView. I see this was accepted. Did you solve it?

Comment: Tested the above structure in the latest Xamarin forms and it compiled fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

[ActivityIndicator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/) has some properties.

IsVisible

IsRunning

IsEnabled

try to set these properties to "true"

Answer (score 1):

**What I have done in my project**

In `Xaml` I have used `Grid` as parent for my `ScrollView`.

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <!----Views----->
  </ScrollView>
        <Frame Padding="50,30,50,30" HasShadow="true" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="actInd" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" />
        </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Page`.
Inside constructor, set

`BindingContext = this;`

After that create `PropertyChangedEventHandler` in your Page with our custom property.

```
private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            isLoading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
    }
```

Now we have just need to change the value of `IsLoading` to show the ActivityIndicator.

```
private void doStuffs()
{
   IsLoading = true;
   IsBusy = true;
   //Do any stuffs
   IsLoading = false;
   IsBusy = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of this talk about putting it in a `StackLayout` is hogwash as far as I'm concerned. Mine is defined in a `Grid`, but does not at all display like it should. When I ran this on Windows 10 (UWP), it would not display at all if only `IsRunning` is set to `true`; but if you set `IsEnabled` or `IsVisible` to `true` *in conjuction* with `IsRunning`, it displays for about two seconds, then fades out and never appears again. Keep in mind, `IsRunning`, `IsEnabled`, and `IsVisible` is only set *once* and *no* time-intensive operations are running on the UI thread.

This is a definitely a bug. I would use an animated GIF until the Xamarin team gets this fixed. It's essentially useless if it can't work on all platforms.